# Screen display size

Tags: java

Hi I'm writing a graphics program and I've been searching for a way to get the physical size of the screen being used. I can get the size of the screen in pixels and also the logical resolution. What I can't seem to find is anywhere to get the physical dimensions that are always in the specs for any monitor (eg 19"- 376 x 301 mm). Question, is this information even stored anywhere in the OS when it loads the driver for the particular screen being used? The program I'm writing needs to work on Mac and Windows.

Thanks!

nt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with java. You can try to write some jni code if this feature is absolutely essential in your program. Otherwise, just ask the user for their monitor size.

**EDIT** Looks like SWT can give you DPI, and you can calculate the monitor size with it:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/org.eclipse.swt.graphics/DevicegetDPI.htm

But, you'd have to use SWT :) Which is actually not that bad choice if you want to develop good-looking programs for Mac.

Comment: how JNI will help in this case? does OS hold this info ?

Comment: The SWT reference sounds really promising! Sure, the SWT lib is not portable but it offers a way to get the dpi as long as the real device offers that info (Printers should, screens maybe too).

Comment: @Andreas_D: SWT is portable, you just distribute your code with different SWT lib for each platform.

Comment: @tulskiy - yes, that's what I wanted to say. With SWT you (usually) have different builds for different platforms, where the difference accross builds is just the SWT lib because that one is platform dependant but available for all major platforms.

Comment: @ntmp: did you switch your whole project to SWT or just this part?

Answer (score 5):

In SWT you can use getShell().getDisplay().getPrimaryMonitor().getClientArea();

```
   final Display display = getShell().getDisplay();  
   final Monitor monitor = display.getPrimaryMonitor();
   final Rectangle rect;
   if (monitor != null) {
      rect = monitor.getClientArea();
   } else {
      // In case we cannot find the primary monitor get the entire display rectangle
      // Note that it may include the dimensions of multiple monitors. 
      rect = display.getBounds();
   }
   System.out.println("Monitor width=" + String.valueOf(rect.width));
   System.out.println("Monitor height=" + String.valueOf(rect.height));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use:

```
Dimension screen = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int pixelPerInch= java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();
double height=screen.getHeight()/pixelPerInch;
double width=screen.getWidth()/pixelPerInch;
double x=Math.pow(height,2);
double y=Math.pow(width,2);
double diagonal= Math.sqrt(x+y);
```

The "diagonal" value is in inches.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

Comment: From java doc: "Returns: the size of this toolkit's screen, in pixels."

Comment: `I can get the size of the screen in pixels and also the logical resolution. What I can't seem to find is anywhere to get the physical dimensions that are always in the specs for any monitor (eg 19"- 376 x 301 mm)`

Answer (score 1):

OK, following Andreas' comments I performed some search and found solution for windows. You can use WMI. WMI can be invoked from java using one of the interoperability tools (jinterop, jintegra, jawin) or by execution of external script (VBScript or JScript). The following script is an example:

```
 strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_DesktopMonitor")

For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
    Wscript.Echo "Caprion: " & objSoftware.Caption
    Wscript.Echo "Description: " & objSoftware.Description
    Wscript.Echo "PixelsPerXLogicalInch: " & objSoftware.PixelsPerXLogicalInch
    Wscript.Echo "ScreenWidth: " & objSoftware.ScreenWidth
Next
```

save it in file screen.vbs and run it using command line `cscript screen.vbs`
Then ScreenWidth/PixelsPerXLogicalInch gives you width in inches.

See `[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389273%28v=VS.85%29.aspx][1]` for more information. I believe that solution for other OS types also exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getScreenResolution()` method of `Toolkit` class which does returns the screen resolution in dots-per-inch. (ref javadocs)

Answer (score 0):

No way with pure Java. The OS doesn't care about physical screen size. Resolution is all it needs. With native code you may be able to get the name of the connected display from the driver and try to look up the technical specs for this type.

As Angus mentioned - it may even be possible that OS or driver can tell a dpi value for the connected screen but even in the best case, at least the screen has to report it's dpi/physical dimensions.

Comment: This is not true. The OS can, and often does, know the physical screen size and DPI. DPI-aware applications can use this to draw things with sizes given in physical dimensions rather than pixels.

Comment: @AlexR - please have a look at the JavaDoc: From java doc: "Returns: the size of this toolkit's screen, in pixels." - ntmp **did not** ask for pixels but for physical dimensions.

Comment: @Angus - OK, so then it may be possible with native code (different for Mac and Windows) and even the best solution may not be able to get the screen size (in inch/cm) for all screens. I bet, screen and driver have to support it.

Comment: Andreas, I am sorry. It seems that I have not read his original question carefully.

Comment: I could see getScreenResolution() in Toolkit class which does 
    Returns the screen resolution in dots-per-inch. (ref JavaDoc) :-)