# Get screen size in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt, screen

How to get screen size in Java?

Not screen resolution, screen/monitor size in inch and aspect ratio.
Application developed has to display some kind of test that has to be the same size regardless to screen size and aspect ratio.
Lets say we want to display a rectangle that is 2 cm wide and 2 cm high and we want it to be the same size for every possible type of display adapter.

Comment: I think it is not possible, because you should know screen DPI to calculate real size, but it [seems not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707756/how-to-correctly-detect-dpi-of-display-with-java) [in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544510/how-to-get-the-screen-dpi-in-java)

Comment: Have you checked this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322253/screen-display-size

Comment: Try `getDefaultTransform ` in `GraphicsConfiguration`.

Comment: What is the screen size of a projector image?  What is the relevance of the number in any case?  Your specification to make something a specific size on-screen makes no sense.

Comment: yes it is.... my client was a terrible idiot and thought that this is relevant in psychological testing.... so all kids could have the same dimensions of area of testing.... it could be relevant.... in very specific case like this

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answer is that it is not achievable in pure Java, and possibly not at all.

You can get hold of the displayable screen size in pixels and the nominal scaling (dpi) in Java, via the default `Toolkit` object.  However, these are often inaccurate ... and that would lead to non-square squares.

You might be able to get more accurate values via native code, but this would definitely be non-portable.  This Q/A says it is impossible - [How to get screen's physical size (i.e. in inches)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263747/how-to-get-screens-physical-size-i-e-in-inches)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an outline of one approach to calibrating a particular display in a test environment:

- Contruct a calibration rectangle that assumes an arbitrary number of pixels/inch (DPI). An estimate may be obtained from `GraphicsConfiguration#getNormalizingTransform()`.
- Render that rectangle scaled to the presumed DPI.
- Add spinners for horizontal and vertical DPI.
- Ask the user to adjust the spinners to make the rectangle have the desired dimensions.
- Record the value(s) in `java.util.Preferences` for subsequent use.
- Use `GraphicsDevice#getIDstring()` to identify specific device calibrations.

Addendum: A similar feature is available in [`ImageJ`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/imagej/info) in the `Analyze > SetScale…` dialog, illustrated in the wiki topic [*SpatialCalibration*](http://wiki.imagej.net/SpatialCalibration).

Comment: and that is a perfect solution for next time :D, user calibration