# JavaFX - Printing size

Tags: javafx

How can you control the size of the printed node?

Ex. I have a Rectangle width = 10 * DPI and height = 5 * DPI.

I want to print this node to be Exactly 10 x 5 inches.
can anyone tell me how to do it programatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322253/screen-display-size, seems highly related, if not duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

you can read out the dpi of the current screen with the following code:

```
double dotsPerInch = Screen.getPrimary().getDpi();
```

be aware that this is the dpi value when the screen is set to its native resolution!

Comment: I also have a discrepancy of about 5% between the calculated size and the actual size on the screen, I think you can't avoid that.

Comment: i think i have found a workaround by multiplying the desired size to 72. i measured the printout with a ruler and its equal to desired inch i want. Although i feel there's a much clever way of coding it.